# Windows+ function takes long to start (windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-explorer

Suddenly, in the last 2-3 days, File explorer is very slow - it takes 60 seconds to open and when I right click on a folder it takes similar time to open the menu. Then I noticed that all functions that I can run by right clicking the Start icon are also  opening very slow, including command prompt, file explorer, control panel, task manager and other. For example, opening Task Manager from the task bar is immediate but from the Start menu it takes almost 3 minutes (2:56 minutes), opening command prompts took 1:06 minutes.

Changes done recently to my computer includes updating windows and adding many files to my Dropbox folder. However, Dropbox says it is now up-to-date. Stopping Dropbox from running (using the task manager) did not help either.
The most annoying problem is the inability to use the File Explorer.

Comment: Have you done a full system scan for malware lately?

Comment: I have ESET32 active on my PC

Comment: Wanted to update. When I clicked on command Prompt or Control Panel in the folder "...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools" which I opened by searching for File Explorer and opening file location, they opened fast. File Explorer was still slow

Comment: Run a full system scan, this is not done by default, it must be user initiated.

Comment: Started full scan now.I'll update later

Comment: Something is wrong with your explorer process. If you haven't already, reboot the pc. That is not shutdown, startup, but actually reboot. If that does not fix it, try creating a new user, and login with that user, is the problem there too or not? if it is, you may have a problem with your harddisk.

Comment: It can not be a problem with the hard disk because all other functions works fine - for example opening a file from word or Excel.However, I'll tray hard boot once the scan is finished.

Comment: Hard Reboot did not solve the problem.

Comment: When running "THIS PC" from the File Explorer file location, it opens fast, but not File Explorer. Also opening "Run" and typing "Cmd" and pressing Enter, opens the command prompt right away. But choosing it from the Windows menu (Right click on the start) is slow

Comment: Adding a new user did not help. The problem persists using the new user

Comment: Problem Solved. A live backup software named WD SmartWare got corrupted and stopped doing live backup, and probably was busying the file lists (monitoring for changes). Once I stopped the process File Explorer runs fine now.